# Get the selected value from a drop-down in angular using reactive forms

Tags: angular

I want to pass hard coded value from the drop down along with the values of the input field of the form. I am using formControllName to get the values and console logging it but I can't pass the value using formControllName from the dropdown because I am not using any input fields, So how can I pass the value to the .ts file and console log it so that I can use a post api to send that value along with the other values

Here is the template file

```
<form style="margin-left: 550px; margin-top: 100px;"  [formGroup] = 'patientForm' (submit) = 'onPatientFormSubmit()'>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h1>Add Patient</h1>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputEmail1" class="form-label">Patient Name</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="name" formControlName="name">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">City</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputCity1" placeholder="City" formControlName="city">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="exampleInputPassword1" class="form-label">Illness</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputIllness1" placeholder="Illness" formControlName="illness">
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown mt-4" formControlName="docid">
        <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
          Select Doctor
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item">action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and here is the component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-patient',
  templateUrl: './add-patient.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-patient.component.css']
})
export class AddPatientComponent implements OnInit {

  patientForm: FormGroup;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.patientForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]),
      city: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]),
      illness: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]),
      docid: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(20)]),
    });
  }

  public onPatientFormSubmit(){
    console.log(this.patientForm.value);
  }

}
```

Comment: There at least 10 questions answered on SO for this

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom component with these features:

1. Glue: Add providers for `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and the multi-provider to extend existing providers. *(Refer to References [1](https://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel))*
2. Machinery: Implement `ControlValueAccessor` to the component to integrate the custom form control value with Angular Reactive Forms. *(Refer to References [1](https://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel) & [2](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor))*

---

### Solution

> app.module.ts

```js
import { CustomDropdownComponent } from './custom-dropdown/custom-dropdown.component';

@NgModule({
  ...
  declarations: [..., CustomDropdownComponent],
})
```

> add-patient.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]='patientForm' style="margin-left: 550px; margin-top: 100px;" (submit)='onPatientFormSubmit()'>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            ...

            <app-custom-dropdown [options]="options" [class]="'mt-4'" [label]="'Select Doctor'" formControlName="docid">
            </app-custom-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> add-patient.component.ts

```js
export class AddPatientComponent implements OnInit {
  options = ['action', 'Another action', 'Something else here'];
  ...
}
```

> custom-dropdown.component.html

```
<div class="dropdown" [ngClass]="class">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
  {{ selectedOption || label  }}
</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
    <li *ngFor="let option of options" (click)="changeSelectedOption(option)">
      <a class="dropdown-item">{{option}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> custom-dropdown.component.ts

```js
import { Component, forwardRef, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './custom-dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-dropdown.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomDropdownComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomDropdownComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
  @Input() options!: string[];
  @Input() class: string | string[] | null;
  @Input() label: string | null;

  selectedOption: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onChange: (_: any) => {};

  writeValue(value: string) {
    this.selectedOption = value;
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => {}) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  changeSelectedOption(option: string) {
    this.selectedOption = option;
    this.onChange(option);
  }

  registerOnTouched() {}
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8cgmze)

---

### References

1. [Connect your custom control to ngModel with Control Value Accessor.](https://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel)
2. [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor)
3. [Bootstrap Dropdown as FormControl in Angular](https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/bootstrap-dropdown-as-formcontrol-in-angular-62fe15f0eec)